# text-align not working with vertical-align

Tags: html, css, vertical-alignment, text-align

I have 6 divs that each contain a `<p>` and a link, and I want them to both be centered, with the `<p>` at the top and the link at the bottom. This is my html (it's basically the same for all 6):

```
<div id="home">
    <p>P</p>
    <a class="nav" href="index.html">home</a>
</div>
```

(all 6 are wrapped in a `<header>`)

This is my css:

```
header div {
  width: 133.33px;
  height: 145px;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 18px;
  padding-bottom: 3px;
  font-weight: lighter;
  float: left;
  display: table;
}

header div a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #474747;
  vertical-align: bottom;
  text-align: center;
  display: table-cell;
}

header div p {
  font-size: 60px;
  padding: 0;
  text-align: center;
  vertical-align: top;
  display: table-cell;
}
```

I can't get the `text-align: center` to work at the same time as the `vertical-align`. Is there anyway to get the top/bottom positioning without using `vertical-align`, or to get the `text-align` to work?

Comment: @jrenk No he doesn't, since he's using table layout

Comment: You can use Position Absolute

Comment: Is this what you're looking for? http://jsfiddle.net/gnjfcktx/

Comment: @Maddy Your code is behaving normally. Both `vertical-align` and `text-align` properties are working as expected http://jsfiddle.net/tb8u0ajc/

Comment: @odedta that does make the text center align but then I can't get the link to bottom align.

Comment: Of course the text is aligned to center, are you looking for an horizontal or vertical align? please explain in detail exactly what you want to achieve, this is rather easy.

Comment: @MohitShrivastava that just makes the link align to the bottom of the page, not the div.

Comment: @odedta I want the text to be vertically aligned at the bottom and horizontally aligned in the center.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's the code you're looking for, I hope: (*These are not the droids you're looking for*)

```css
.wrapper {
    text-align: center;
    height: 200px;
    width: 200px;
    border: 1px solid black;
    display: table;
}
.container {
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: bottom;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="container">
        <p>Hello World!</p>
        <a href="#">I am a Link!</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

following Alohci's comment, if you'd like the `<p>` tags at the top and `<a>` tags at the bottom you should use the `position` property as follows:

```css
.wrapper {
    position: relative;
    text-align: center;
    height: 200px;
    max-height: 200px;
    width: 200px;
    max-width: 200px;
    border: 1px solid black;
    display: table;
}
.container p {
    display: inline;
    vertical-align: top;
}
.container a {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="container">
        <p>Hello World!</p>
        <a href="#">I am a Link!</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: `<p>` at the top, the question says.

Comment: @Alohci, the OP commented on his post with this: `@odedta I want the text to be vertically aligned at the bottom and horizontally aligned in the center. –  Maddy 11 mins ago`

Comment: Nice explanation bro

Answer (score 0):

Use Following CSS,
You Can Get a `<p>` and a link both be at centered,

```
div {
  width: 133.33px;
  height: 145px;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 18px;
  padding-bottom: 3px;
  font-weight: lighter;
  float: left;
  display: table;
}

 div a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #474747;
  vertical-align: middle;

  display: table-cell;
}

 div p {
  font-size: 60px;
  padding: 0;
  text-align: center; 
}
```

Here is the Jsfiddle solution link.

http://jsfiddle.net/rbdqtxyf/